# SQL query looping for each value in a list

Tags: sql, loops, azure-sql-database, each

New to SQL here - I am trying to get 1 row from a table matching to a particular criteria

Typically this would look like

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE id = 'abc'
```

The output may look like

```
 value    id
--------------
  1       abc
```

The table has many entries for an 'id', and I am trying to get one entry per 'id'. Now I have list of 'id's. How would I execute something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM myTable
FOR EACH id
WHERE id IN ('abc', 'edf', 'fgh')
```

Expecting result like

```
 value    id
 --------------
  1       abc
  10      edf
  12      fgh
```

I do not know if it is some sort union or concat operation, but would like to learn. I am working on Azure SQL Server

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> The table has many entries for an 'id', and I am trying to get one entry per 'id'. Now I have list of 'id's.

A typical method is `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  you can filter on particular ids, if you want.  It is unclear if that is really required for your question.

If you happen to be using SQL Server (as `select top` suggests), you can use the more concise, but somewhat less performant:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from mytable t
order by row_number() over (order by id order by (select null));
```

Comment: Not sure, I ran into trouble running the commands - may have been related to me using sql azure server?

Comment: @user6386155 . . . Azure supports window functions, so I don't think that is the issue.